# How do you populate package variables when testing a class's method in Pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm writing a test suite for a class that needs variables from a `util` package I have defined:

```py
# util/__init__.py

codes = None

def load_codes():
    """Populates util.codes with the contents of codes.yml"""
    with open('codes.yml', 'r') as f:
        global codes
        codes = yaml.safe_load(f)
```

The class under test, Filter, is a plugin for a larger app; normally `util.load_codes()` is called on startup of the app, so when Filter needs to read `util.codes`, it is guaranteed to be populated. Filter should not be concerned with loading the file into the package var.

For the test itself, I'm loading the class instance as a fixture:

```py
# tests/filter.py
import pytest
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock
from plugins.filter import Filter

@pytest.fixture
def filterplugin():
    bot = AsyncMock()
    return Filter(bot=bot)


@pytest.mark.asyncio
class TestFilterLogic:
    async def test_basic(self, filterplugin):
        msg = AsyncMock()
        output = await filterplugin.filter_handler(msg)
        assert output == True
```

Filter itself is large and complicated, but a MVP that demonstrates the problem is:

```py
# plugins/filter.py
from util import codes

class Filter():
    async def filter_handler(self):
        print(codes.keys())
        return True
```

This test fails with an `AttributeError` when `filter_handler` calls `.keys()` on `util.codes`; it's None.

I attempted to fix this by calling importing `util` and calling `util.load_codes()` both in the fixture and in the test itself, to no effect. The test still fails and indicates that the `codes` var in `util` is None.

How do I correctly populate this package variable so my class can read it when being unit tested independently of the rest of the larger app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when `Filter` needs to read `util.codes`

The implementation shown does not read `util.codes`. It reads a local reference to the value of `util.codes` at import time, i.e. a local reference to `None`. That local variable will not be modified by `load_codes()`.

There are a few ways to resolve this.

1. Initialize `codes` as a dictionary and modify that instance (not reassign) in `load_codes()`.

```
# util/__init__.py

# codes = None  # -
codes = {}      # +

def load_codes():
    """Populates util.codes with the contents of codes.yml"""
    with open('codes.yml', 'r') as f:
        global codes
        # codes = yaml.safe_load(f)      # -
        codes.clear()                    # +
        codes.update(yaml.safe_load(f))  # +
```

2. Import the module and reference the module variable as an attribute of the module.

```py
# plugins/filter.py

# from util import codes  # -
import util               # +

class Filter():
    async def filter_handler(self):
        # print(codes.keys())     # -
        print(util.codes.keys())  # +
        return True
```

3. Import the module variable as a local variable lazily.

```py
# plugins/filter.py

# from util import codes        # -

class Filter():
    async def filter_handler(self):
        from util import codes  # +
        print(codes.keys())
        return True
```

4. Import `Filter` lazily, assuming `load_codes()` is called before the fixture.

```py
# tests/filter.py

import pytest
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock
# from plugins.filter import Filter    # -

@pytest.fixture
def filterplugin():
    from plugins.filter import Filter  # +
    bot = AsyncMock()
    return Filter(bot=bot)
```